# how to I scale an hour hand image to be small in Interface Builder (without moving center)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, xcode4, interface-builder

How to I scale an hour hand image to be small in Interface Builder (without moving center)?

So I have:

- Background clock face image
- Arrow image that is about 30% to big, needs to be reduced
- The Background clock face is set to: View Mode = ASPECT FIT (in IB).  Plus resizes in each diretion.
- I'm not sure what View Mode the Hour Hand should be at.  I've currently set it to Centre, however in priciple I want it to resize (aspect resize) in relation to how much the clock face done during an orientation change.

When resizing it it would have to:

- Not change the center of the image, as I've created the images such that they align well when centred together
- Not be impacted by the "transformation" of the hour hand UIView which is how I move it around
- Work for orientation changes